# How do I make my monitor not use any color profile at all?

Tags: colors

I want a color profile that is straight 1:1 color mapping. I'll try to explain what I mean the best I can.

For example, if I open an image file that has a pixel with the following RGB values: (Red: 127, Green: 127, Blue: 127), the corresponding pixel on my display should light up to ~49.8% as bright as its maximum brightness.

Such a color profile would have no space transformations. No need for a specified gamut, gamma correction, custom color responses, etc. Just a direct 1:1 color input and output.

In other words, the image data is directly sent to the LEDs without any color adjustments.

Where can I get a color profile like that?

Comment: Do you know why people install color profiles in the first place, or put a lot of effort into creating a color profile for a monitor?  Also, it sounds like you have digital data.  Where did the digital data come from, and what makes you feel that it accurately represents the original colors (e.g. from a photograph)?

Comment: Your example assumes the hardware response is perfectly "linear" by itself. Quotes because I guess the eye perceives light in a logarithmic manner; you probably want the response to *appear* linear to the eye. There's no magic that gives you this by default. Starting from the hardware level we deliberately adjust color response to appear more perfect. And at the end even two twin items of the same brand may vary slightly, so each will need its own color profile if you're really demanding. The gist of your example is exactly what color profiles are for in the first place.

Comment: What's more, you naively assume that the camera correctly translates colors to RGB, and that after translation by the camera, display driver and monitor, the colors would still have some correspondence to the real world. Well, no, that's what color profiles are for.

Comment: If a camera is involved, @harrymc is right. But we can consider images created (rendered) without the camera, e.g. in Blender, and the story with monitors is the same. "No color profile" is in fact "some random color profile, specific to the device". You superimpose additional color profile to compensate this.

Comment: Just to add to Kamil Maciorowski's comments, even if you are starting with synthetically produced "perfect" color, the monitor isn't perfect.  The hardware and process it uses to produce visual output creates an approximation, and relies on a color profile to correct the irregularities and imperfections.  Without a color profile, your example would not necessarily be neutral gray or 49.8% of its maximum brightness.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your monitor to display accurate color, like a "straight 1:1 color match" with the intended image colors, you should get and use an accurate color profile for your monitor. There is no "default" or "straight" setting, color profiles try to recreate accurate colors.

From Neil Barstow's websitse [colour management, why do I need it? why is colour management important?](http://www.colourmanagement.net/the-basics/why-do-i-need-colour-management):

> Anyone who has ever scanned an image or taken a digital photo, looked at it on a computer screen and then printed it can easily appreciate why we need colour management in digital imaging. Those things don't just automatically "match" and colour management is what solves the riddle of "why not?"
>
> Input, display and output devices do not interpret digital colour the same way.
>
> ...
>
> In the mid 90's, the introduction of Apple's Colorsync 2.0 technology was a milestone in colour management on the desktop. This system level software enabled the use of device profiles, these profiles characterize the devices we use by measuring the way those individual devices reproduce special test charts during the process of scanning or capture, printing or viewing. Microsoft introduced similar system level colour in Windows 2000.

Wikipedia says this about [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile):

> In color management, an ICC profile is a set of data that characterizes a color input or output device, or a color space, according to standards promulgated by the International Color Consortium (ICC). ... Every device that captures or displays color can be profiled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want straight RGB display (which in many cases you get anyway by default),
you should be using RGB graphics without any color profile.

There are two places where a color profile may be specified.

## Windows color profile removal

This is how to find if Windows is using a color profile and remove it.
I would suggest to ensure first that you know how to re-install the
color profiles to be removed, before doing the operation described below.

- Click the *Start* button, type *Color Management* and run it
- In the Color Management dialog, click the Devices tab, and then click your display
- Ensure that *Use my settings for this device* is selected
- Under *Profiles Associated with this Device*, remove all the listed
- To remove a profile, select it and click *Remove*
- When the box list is empty, click Close.

If the list is already empty, then Windows is not using any color profile
for the display, which is a common occurrence.

[image]

## Image color profile removal

Many images will contain an embedded color profile, in most cases when the image
is produced by a camera, with the intention of making the displayed image colors
be true for any kind of display device. Most cameras don't have any setting for
disabling this option, but some do.

Another source for color profiles in images is the image editor when dealing with
digital images. If you wish to avoid a color profile in the image,
you should specify in the editor the *sRGB* color profile,
which is basically RGB.

For example, in the GIMP image editor you would use the
[Discard Color Profile command](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-discard-color-profile.html)
to discard the image's currently assigned ICC profile and instead
assign the GIMP's built-in sRGB profile.
You can access this command from the Image menu bar through
*Image → Color Management → Discard Color Profile*:

[image]

If you happen across an image containing a color profile that you wish to remove,
you may do that in an image editor, by specifying the *sRGB* color profile.
Or you may use another image-editing software product.

For example, for
[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)
the command may be one of:

```
convert input.jpg +profile icm output.jpg
convert input.jpg +profile "*" output.jpg
```

For more information, see ImageMagick documentation for
[Image Profiles](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#profiles).

Comment: @clickbait: Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't care how shitty the screen looks. I'm doing maths with pixels. I want the value returned by the colour picker to be the result of the maths operations, not some "calibrated" skewed interpolation made to "look pretty".

How can I make my screen look shitty but accurate with direct "1:1" pixel values?

[EDIT] I fixed the issue by denying access to the ICC folder to all users:
`$ sudo chmod 000 ~/.local/share/icc`